# Is it possible to create a ProgressBar without having to run it on a new thread?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have been looking at a lot of Progress Bar examples, and they all involve creating a new thread, or an async task.
Those kinds of progress bar are the ones that pop up, updates, and disappears when the task is done.

However, I am interested into creating a permanent ProgressBar in my app that can actually be updated by hard coding the progress.

so here is an example code:

```
ProgressBar levelProgress;
levelProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById( R.id.progressBarLevel);
levelProgress.setMax(100);
levelProgress.setProgress(50); //this is what I wanted to do
```

I want to have the ProgressBar to stay as it is,
So with the code above, I was expecting to have a permanent ProgressBar located in my layout to be half completed.
What I actually have is an empty ProgressBar.

The final question is, is there any way to hard code the update of a progress bar? or is it only available through an AsyncTask or a runnable Thread?

Edit : I forgot to mention that I am implementing this as a Fragment.
a slightly more complete code would be as follows

```
public class myLevelDisplayActivity extends Fragment{

LinearLayout ll;
static FragmentActivity fa;
ProgressBar levelProgress;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fa = super.getActivity();
    ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.levelDisplay, container, false);

       levelProgress = (ProgressBar) ll.findViewById( R.id.progressBarLevel);
       levelProgress.setMax(100);
       levelProgress.setProgress(0);
       levelProgress.setProgress(10);
       levelProgress.setProgress(50);

 return ll;
}
```

levelDisplay.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,ExtraText,ExtraText,ExtraText,ExtraText,ExtraText" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCurrentLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/circle1" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.26"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewLevelTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Level Title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBarLevel"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3.16"
                    android:max="100" 
                    />



            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="3.16" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewCurrent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Current"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSeparator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewNextLimit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Next Level"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current code seems fine . you should show more code if there is still a problem .

also, the threads are just not related to the problem , since they are used only to show that it can advance.

btw , you can use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead of a new thread.

Comment: I have added more code in my original question.
Please do have a look at it if you can.
Thank you

Comment: what did you try to achieve by calling "setProgress" 3 times?

Comment: also , what do you see that doesn't fit your expectation?

Comment: I have just tried to set it 5 times, i've set it to 0 ->1 ->2 ->10 ->50 , and still no luck.

What I expected was to have the progress bar in my layout to display 50% progress, but what actually came out was as if it has 0% progress on it.

I have slipped through several Logs in between the  setProgress method calls just to make sure that the code was being executed, and I have confirmed that all of the setProgress were executed, but still no change with the progress bar... it stays at 0%

Comment: do you run the app on an emulator? did you update ADT&SDK to the latest version ? where is the activity that uses the fragment? how did you use the fragment within the activity ? can you also show the XML file "levelDisplay" ?

Comment: I ran the app on the emulator, on Galaxy S2 & Galaxy S3
I did update the ADT & just downloaded 4.1 and Update the rest about 2 weeks ago. 

the activity that uses the fragment is a FragmentActivity that implements TabHost & ViewPager, the code is too long to put up here.

Basically what I did with the fragment is to achieve a swipey tab interface.

I'll update my original question with the XML of the levelDisplay

Comment: and you are sure that the rest of the views (those of this fragment) are shown fine ? you've also tested a simple project with a single activity that shows a progressBar , just to feel that you control it... ?

Comment: other than the missing image which i've replaced with another one) , the layout&code works fine for me , so it's probably something else . try to put a totally different view instead of the progress bar and check that it's shown . do you have any other code in the fragment that might cause problems? maybe, in another fragment (or in the activity ) you find this progressBar and change it to something else (or change its visibility) ? it could happen since you use the default name of the progressBar.

Comment: You are right, I just tried making it on a plain normal activity, and it works. So the problem is probably caused by the Fragment.
I'll have a look into it more.
I have been using the FragmentActivity for quite some time, and I've had various different things there, they all worked just fine.. except this progress bar.
Thank you for narrowing down the problem for me.
Please let me know if you have found a possible solution.
Mean while I will try to solve it

Comment: try to use the samples as something to look at , and just put the progress bar there . i'm sure it will work there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop a ProgressBar in your Layout (theres one under form widgets). 
I dont know if you can set the progress percentage from XML, if not you can set it programmatically like that: (this is just from the top of my head):

```
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar); 
pb.setProgress(50);
```

Comment: I actually already did exactly like that.
I've got a progress bar in my layout, with that example code above, and some how it does not show any progress at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set progress from XML and code without a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`. Your problem is either that your code does not run or you have a problem in your layout.
Layout XML should either have `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` or a customized set of the attributes contained in that style. See [Using a Horizontal Progress Bar in Android](http://bytecrafter.blogspot.de/2008/12/using-horizontal-progress-bar-in.html)

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarLevel"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50" />
```

> The final question is, is there any way to hard code the update of a progress bar?

Yes, the reason for `Thread`/`AsyncTask` is that people want to change the progress over time but you don't want to do that you don't have to use it.

Comment: I do not understand what's wrong here, my Layout XML file contains exactly what you wrote as a ProgressBar, I didn't have the android:progress before, but I have tried putting it in, and still no progress at all.. it still looks like a 0% progress on it =(

Comment: I have added some extra code to show more of what I am doing, I forgot to mention before that I am implementing this in a Fragment activity